# Natural numbers n which satisfy gnu(n)=n?

Tags: gr.group-theory, open-problems

Are there any natural numbers $n$ (other than 1) for which $gnu(n)=n$? We define $gnu(n)$ to 
be the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $n$. This question popped into my head today, and I couldn't come up with a proof one way or another.

In the paper by Conway, et al. entitled ["Counting Groups: Gnus, Moas, and other Exotica](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf%20%22Counting%20Groups%3A%20Gnus,%20Moas,%20and%20other%20Exotica%22), Conjecture 10.1 implies that there should be no such natural number $n$ which satisfies $gnu(n)=n$.

Does anybody have an argument to show that there is no natural number $n$ (other than 1) for which $gnu(n)=n$? If it is really straightforward, just say so and I'll work it out for myself when I find time. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ is the number of (isomorphism classes of) finite groups of order $n$.

Comment: In the paper you linked to they call such an $n$ group-perfect; they also state that they don't know if there is any group-perfect number other than 1. So I'm tempted to say that this is an open problem, though I'd be happy to be corrected.

Comment: If a 2008 paper (with John Conway as an author) says that the problem is open, then I think we can safely say that it is open and not at all trivial.

Comment: OK, I guess I should probably delve a bit deeper into that paper. Sorry for not doing my homework well enough!

Comment: MR shows two papers that refer to the Conway et al paper: May, Coy L.; Zimmerman, Jay, The 2-groups of odd strong symmetric genus, J. Algebra Appl. 9 (2010), no. 3, 465–481, and Curran, M. John, Groups of cube-free odd order, Amer. Math. Monthly 117 (2010), no. 4, 363–365. Whether either sheds light on the current question, I don't know. 

Comment: dunno if the following will be useful to you: http://oeis.org/A046057